# Batch File with two conditions and a loop

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, conditional-statements, errorlevel

Let us assume my only method of scripting is via a batch file.

I have a batch file with a long list of commands, however, I need to include two contingencies:

- Needs to be on the domain (we'll use .com for this example)
- Must have a non typical IP (meaning 192 is not used on the domain, but is used prior to joining and not 169 due to delay in DHCP assignment).

I'd prefer to keep this in the same batch file as the rest of the code. I've tried sewing together some commands, but usually get a syntax error. I am able to make the IP portion work, using %ERRORLEVEL% however, I can only figure out searching for a single IP mask.

Here is a VERY wrong and rudimentary code:

```
    @ECHO off

    for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('SYSTEMINFO ^| FIND /I "DOMAIN:"') do (
        IF %%G == ".com" (
            GOTO :IPCheck
        ) ELSE ( GOTO :NoRun

    :IPCheck
    ipconfig | find /i "192." "169."
        if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto IPCheck


     REM Domain address is configured and will continue script.)
    pause
    )
```

Comment: If you want us to help you to fix a specific issue with your code, you need to include a [mcve] of it directly in your question and formatted appropriately using the **`{}`** button. You will also need to explain exactly what that code is supposed to do and what it does which differs from the intent, including any error messages returned.

Comment: `IF` comparisons are literal. If you have quotes on one side of the comparison they must be on the other side for it to be true. Also there is no reason to put all of that code execution within the `FOR /F` code execution. Just assign the `FOR /F` output to an environmental variable.  It would be quicker to use the variable `USERDNSDOMAIN` then parsing the output of `SYSTEMINFO`.

Comment: Thanks you for the input! I need to make sure the workstations are joined to the domain AND have a valid network IP address. If neither exist, it should skip the rest of the code and end the script.

Comment: Well - on your published code, you're attempting to use a label within a code block. Not allowed for all intents and purposes. `find` does not allow multiple search-strings - you need `findstr`  - and your string-selection would match `xxx.yyy.192.zzz` for instance - probably not what is intended.

Comment: `ipconfig |find "IPv4"|find " 192." >nul && echo yes || echo no`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` isn't able to look for more than one search string. `Findstr` is. See `findstr /?` for more information.

You don't even need any sort of loop:

```
@echo off
ipconfig | find "IPv4" | findstr /c:" 192." /c:" 169." >nul && goto :NoRun    
systeminfo | findstr /RBE "Domain:.*\.com" >nul || goto :NoRun
echo all ok. Insert payload here...
goto :eof
:NoRun
echo this system doesn't meet the prerequisites.
```

Comment: Stephan, my understanding was that the OP didn't want lP Addresses beginning with `192` or `169`, so I'm assuming that line `3` should use `&&` instead of `||`. I'd also suggest, due to the time taken to load and run `SystemInfo`, that you switch lines `2` and `3`.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow @Stephan. Thank you! My coworker and I came up with something similar, but he is using IPv4 for the domain check, but I'm not a fan of his method.

I will report back!
Just a little more background, we're an MDT imaging group, we have several batch files (don't ask), that install pieces of software in a required order. The computers are imaged on a "private network", and once the image process is over, we join the workstations to the domain and have to run these two batch files while they're on the network. So we need to confirm an IP and the domain.